# Does anyone know the name of this card game?

Tags: identify-this-game

The game is played with a standard 52 card deck.

I start by dealing cards to each player plus a dummy hand next to the dealer and the last card goes into the middle.
Then three pots are made up.

- Pot one is first person to get a three card run.
- Pot two is the queen pot of you play the queen that matches the card suit in the middle at the end you claim the pot.
- Pot three is first person to be out of cards.

Dealer looks at his hand and decides if they want to keep it or change to the dummy hand. This continues around the table until someone accepts the dummy hand.

The game then starts by someone playing an ace but I can't remember which one, then the game continues in suit order.

That's roughly what I remember.

Comment: Is this played with a standard 52 card deck?

Comment: Yes it is. The dummy hand has one extra card

Comment: Sounds a lot like Rummy Royal, but some of the specifics seem off.

Comment: Is it a trick taking game?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trick-taking_game

Answer (score 2):

We used to play this game with our grandma from Leeds over 40 years ago. We knew it as Queenie. She used to keep us up until she won all our money.
We are trying to remember the rules and thats how we found your post.

When we played we only had two pots one for the queen and one for finishing first. I thought we used to bid for the spare hand, but I could be wrong.

Yours is the first mention of the game I have found online.

Comment: Unless you have a link to rules for Queenie, this seems better suited as a comment than an answer.