# Does anyone know the card game "King Up"?

Tags: identify-this-game

I used to play a card game called "King Up" with my nana and siblings, but my nana has passed and my siblings and I have forgotten how it's played. I'd be grateful if someone recognises it and can remind me of the rules!

Things I remember:

- in the centre of the table there was a face-up Jack of Diamonds, a blank space, and a face-down mystery card, each of which we would bet on - there were therefore three possible "pots" to win each round
- there was a dummy hand
- it was a run-based game, NOT a trick-based game
- whoever held the 2 of Diamonds would start
- the Jack of Diamonds "pot" could be won by playing the King of Diamonds
- the blank space "pot" could be won by getting rid of all your cards
- the "pots" carried over into the next round if no one won them

A previous query on here ([Does anyone know the name of this card game?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/29249/does-anyone-know-the-name-of-this-card-game)) is very similar, but doesn't actually explain how the game is played.

I hope someone can help!

Comment: Sounds like a variant of Boodle/Michigan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newmarket_(card_game)